# Where to create UserControl for ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my application I have a window with several buttons on the top. By a click on one button a usercontrol is displayed in a contentcontrol under the buttons.

All buttons are bound to one Command in the ViewModel. The decission which usercontrol should be displayed is done by the commandparameter with an enum like:

```
<Button Content="Pupils" Margin="3" Height="30" Command="{Binding OpenSectionCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Static local:SectionType.Section1}"/>
```

My question now is: Where shall I create the new Usercontrol and assign it to the ContentControl?

I had several ideas:

1. Bind the Content direct to the ViewModel and assign the new
   UserControl there
2. Bind the Enum and use a converter to create the control

Comment: Do you have separate UserControls for different Content?

Comment: Yes. For each button I have a serveral UserControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for each type of `Content` you have separate `UserControls`, i would suggest to use [ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

1. Create `DataTemplates` for multiple userControls you have and put them under window resources.
2. Have a `ContentControl` in your window and bind its Content to selected content property in ViewModel.
3. Create a `ContentTemplateSelector` and based on content selected return corresponding DataTemplate.

XAML:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedContent}"
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ContentSelector}"/>
```

Refer to the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This way in future if you need to add another content, all you had to do is create a `DataTemplate` for it under resources and put the check in `ContentSelector` and you are good to go. (easily extensible).